# Any way to force read next line while in StreamReader loop?

Tags: vb.net, while-loop, streamreader

I'm working on a txt file and I was wondering if there was a way to force the streamreader to read the next line after I've used the value of the one it currently read.

My code:

```
Private Sub subTest()
    Dim sr As New StreamReader("d:\input\cleanedUp.txt")
    Dim doc As New XmlDocument
    Dim root As XmlElement = doc.CreateElement("Views")
    Dim ns As String = sr.ReadLine()
    Dim nsAtt As XmlAttribute = doc.CreateAttribute("ClientCode")
    nsAtt.Value = ns
    root.Attributes.Append(nsAtt)

    While Not sr.EndOfStream
        Dim sLine As String = sr.ReadLine

        doc.AppendChild(root)
        Dim child As XmlElement = doc.CreateElement("View")
        root.AppendChild(child)
        Dim newAtt As XmlAttribute = doc.CreateAttribute("Name")
        newAtt.Value = sLine
        child.Attributes.Append(newAtt)

        Dim subChild As XmlElement = doc.CreateElement("Criteria")
        child.AppendChild(subChild)
        subChild.InnerText = sLine
    End While
    sr.Close() : sr.Dispose()

    Dim sett As New XmlWriterSettings
    sett.Indent = True

    Dim sw As XmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create("d:\input\data.xml", sett)
    doc.Save(sw)
    sw.Flush() : sw.Close()
End Sub
```

Result is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Views ClientCode="WSMCABS">
    <View Name="vACCESSONE">
        <Criteria>vACCESSONE</Criteria>
    </View>
    <View Name="ACCESSONE">
        <Criteria>ACCESSONE</Criteria>
    </View>
</Views>
```

What I want is this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Views ClientCode="WSMCABS">
    <View Name="vACCESSONE">
        <Criteria>ACCESSONE</Criteria>
    </View>
    <View Name="vSample2">
        <Criteria>SAMPLE2</Criteria>
    </View>
</Views>
```

Comment: I agree with @SLaks, why not just call the ReadLine() function of your streamreader? Would you mind posting an example of your code?

Comment: Post the cleanup.txt used as input.
ditto call readline() - each call consumes a line. Note your code consumes one line in the DIM ns before you get to the While Loop. Using your flow logic move Dim sLine... where Dim ns is, then at the bottom of the While loop use sLine = Readline() to load the next line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue I was having was pretty much that the reader would create a new child/subchild for every line read, and instead I wanted a child with multiple subchilds. So it's a bit of a hack, but I was able to accomplish this by setting a loop with certain conditions that applied to my situation. This may not be the best answer for anyone else out there trying to accomplish something similar, but it worked for me since my text file was composed of SQL views that began with a "v" followed by the criteria for that particular view. The program then breaks out of adding additional subchild nodes when it sees that another view (starting with "v") is read on the line.

```
While Not sr.EndOfStream

        doc.AppendChild(root)
        Dim child As XmlElement = doc.CreateElement("View")
        root.AppendChild(child)
        Dim newAtt As XmlAttribute = doc.CreateAttribute("Name")
        newAtt.Value = sLine
        child.Attributes.Append(newAtt)

        If sLine.StartsWith("v") Then
            sLine = sr.ReadLine
            While Not sLine.StartsWith("v")
                Dim subChild As XmlElement = doc.CreateElement("Criteria")
                child.AppendChild(subChild)
                subChild.InnerText = sLine
                sLine = sr.ReadLine
                If sLine = Nothing Then
                    sLine = sr.ReadLine
                End If
                If sLine = Nothing Then
                    Exit While
                End If
            End While
        End If

    End While
    sr.Close() : sr.Dispose()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can test whether there is another line available within the loop and perform another ReadLine:

```
While Not sr.EndOfStream
    Dim sLine As String = sr.ReadLine
    DoSomethingWithLine(sLine)

    If Not sr.EndOfStream Then
        sLine = sr.ReadLine
        DoSomethingElseWithLine(sLine)
    End If
End While
```